# How to configure AWS classic load balancer to use AWS SSL for both 80 and 8080?

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, rtmp, amazon-acm

We are using Nginx-RTMP Streaming and trying to redirect both 80 and 8080 to https. We have tried with redirecting different SSL port in AWS Classic load balancer but its doesn't work.

Nginx RTMP Statistics URL->http://domainname:8080/stats

Please provide an solution to use aws SSL for both 80 and 8080

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying different Load Balancer Protocols (tcp/80 and tcp/8080) in "Step 1: Define Load Balancer" of the Classic ELB wizard?

if you are looking for 301 style redirects, Classic ELB does not [support those](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/). You will have better luck with the Application ELB as [describe here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#redirect-actions).

Comment: Have mentioned both ports in load balancer listener. Please find the updated listener below 1-> 80 to 80 2-> 8080 to 8080 3-> 443 to 80

Comment: Is it due to redirection done under application load balancer configured for main domain example.com?